# Entity Framework app backed by MySQL works only on my PC

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I created this application in Windows Forms which is managing MySQL database by Entity Framework. I've published it and installed on my system and it worked fine... but when I've send it to my friend and he tried to run it, there is this error (sorry for my bad translation there]:

> System.TypeInitializationException: [type initiator prompted error for type] 'Kwestionariusz.Stuff.EntityManager'. ---> System.ArgumentException: [the supplier of the warehouse can't be found in the configuration or it isn't correct] ---> System.ArgumentException: [can't find wanted supplier of application data. it's possible that it's not installed].
>       [in] System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
>       [in] System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)

What they want me to install and why wasn't it installed by the installation of my software?

Comment: yeah, I don't like that it's in my language as it's hard to find any information... I should Google how to change it :)

Comment: @sms if you ever find out how to change the language of exceptions, let me know :P

Comment: Please make sure that your friend's machine has the corresponding .NET framework installed. See [Deployment Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896268%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Pacane I guess that's impossible as I have english version of VS and the environment is also set to english... still, exceptions are in my language. since windows 8, I will buy english version :)

Comment: @JiajiWu that was my 1st thought but after the installation of the framework - it's still the same error.

Comment: @sms, could it be the [ADO.NET driver for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) that's missing on your friend's machine?

Comment: @sms if you want every exceptions was in english start write application in english I mean namespaces/classes/enum and so on `Kwestionariusz.Stuff.EntityManager` this is inn polish because you have namespace which got this name `Kwestionariusz` Like you can see your exception trace is in English only this namespaces or Classes r in polish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you install on your target machine the MySQL accessor components? They are not included in .NET framework and you probably istalled them too before start your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about this technology, but do you need a odbc or an other alternative data definition on the individual pc that the application knowns where to get the data?

out you your description i could not read you've done this and also the error message seems to show this kind if a problem?

all the best

Comment: data is taken from the external database on the web server only